# How do I center one div to the bottom and make another realizable one in the center?

Tags: html, css, image, center

So I'm trying to create a div that displays and image and has a title of the image at the bottom. The image should be have enough room so that it isn't stretched and look weird.Then I want to take that div and reproduce it over and over for as many images as I have.

I drew and image of what I'm trying! to describe I hope you guys and understand it.

[image: div drawings]

This is the code I have so far. I know its not a lot but I'm a little lost.

```css
.box{
 height:250px;
 width:200px;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-right:15px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 float:left;
 background-color:yellow;
}

.photo-div{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background-color:blue;
}

.title-wrap{
 height:40px;
 width: 200px; 
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="photo-div">
 </div>
    <div class="title-wrap">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might look at bootstrap's grid system to use that or mimic the behavior. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```css
.box{
 height:250px;
 width:200px;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-right:15px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 float:left;
 background-color:yellow;
}

.row{
 height:70px;
 width:200px;
    display: inline;
}

.column{
 height:70px;
 width:50px;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}

.photo-div{
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background-color:blue;
}

.title-wrap{
 height:20px;
 width: 50px; 
 background:pink;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
         <div class="photo-div">
                <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty_office_3/48/Globe.png"/>               
         </div>
            <div class="title-wrap">IMG</div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking for a one image and the a title to it. Then have 20 of those even spaced in a content wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
http://jsfiddle.net/jtx16Lf2/7/

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="box">
    <script>
         for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
                var image = document.createElement('div');
                var titleBar = document.createElement('div');
                image.className = "photo-div";
                titleBar.className = "title-wrap";
                document.getElementById('box').appendChild(image);
                document.getElementById('box').appendChild(titleBar);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box{
    height:750px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
}

.photo-div{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-left:35%;
    margin-top:20%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.title-wrap{
    height:40px;
    width: 200px; 
    background:pink;
    margin-top:105%;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this but instead of a 1 by the for loop some thing where I could a 4 x 3 set of those squares with spacing in the middle. And being able to add one if I have an odd amount of images.